# Azure Functions Get Parameters from calling endpoint

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to implement a method that return the parameter's names for any called Azure function

If I have this Azure function code:

```
[FunctionName("Something")]
 public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "customer/{param1}/{param2}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string param1, string param2, TraceWriter log)
 {

     //get the route params by calling the helper function
     //my body
 }
```

- If I  would call the function endpoint using :
  http://localhost:80/customer/1/2
- Output of the helper function -> ['param1', 'param2']

My Possible approaches:

1. I am trying to use the `StackTrace` and search for "Run" function,
   but I cannot get into the parameter names.
2. Use `HttpRequestMessage`: I can found the url but with values in it, however i need the actual names of the parameters

Comment: `I am trying to implement a helper function that return the parameter's names for any called function` I don't think that you could call the help function to get parameters of any function, it also seems hack. Based on my understanding, if you want to call an function and try to get the expected result, you need to implement it in your Azure function it self. In your case, you could use the `var p1 = nameof(param1) and var p2 = nameof(param2)` to get the parameter name in the function.

Comment: The helper function is not an azure function. It's just a utility function.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I don't think there is a way just can the endpoint to get parameter names of the endpoint, except you are the owner of the endpoint and give them as output.

Answer (score 1):

Route Attribute(along with other trigger info) is built into `function.json`. File structure is as below.

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.21",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "route": "customer/{param1}/{param2}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/FunctionAppName.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionAppName.FunctionName.Run"
}
```

So one tricky way is to read `function.json`.

Add `ExecutionContext context` to method signature so that we can get function directory directly.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "customer/{param1}/{param2}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string param1, string param2, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
 {

     //get the route params by calling the helper function
     GetRouteParams(context, log);
     //my body
 }

    public static void GetRouteParams(ExecutionContext context, TraceWriter log)
    {
        //function.json is under function directory
        using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText(context.FunctionDirectory + "/function.json"))
        {
            // Deserialize json
            dynamic jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r.ReadToEnd());
            string route = jObject.bindings[0].route.ToString();

            // Search params name included in brackets
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(route);

            var list = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToList();
            log.Info("[" + string.Join(", ", list) + "]");
        }
    }
```